# How connect to mongodb by authenticated user string url

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to connect to mongodb by following string url

```
DATA = "mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/ais_mlm?authSource=admin"
```

here is db file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//const mongoDB = "mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/ais_mlm?authSource=admin";
const chalk = require('chalk');
const path = require('path');
const connected = chalk.bold.cyan;
const error = chalk.bold.yellow;
const disconnected = chalk.bold.red;
const termination = chalk.bold.magenta;
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
console.log('here...', path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'),process.env.DATA);

 mongoose.connect(process.env.DATA, async(err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("conncted to db")
  }
 );

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(){
    console.log(connected("Mongoose default connection is open to ", process.env.DATA));
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(error("Mongoose default connection has occured "+err+" error"));
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(){
    console.log(disconnected("Mongoose default connection is disconnected"));
});

process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    mongoose.connection.close(function(){
        console.log(termination("Mongoose default connection is disconnected due to application termination"));
        process.exit(0)
    });
});
```

here is env

DATA = "mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/ais_mlm?authSource=admin"

here is my createUser in db by command

```
> show users
{
        "_id" : "ais_mlm.Admin",
        "userId" : UUID("04c87ab3-4129-4e8f-ab8a-d76c385dc5d4"),
        "user" : "Admin",
        "db" : "ais_mlm",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",        
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "ais_mlm.admin",
        "userId" : UUID("e7f7d693-151b-4db7-b3c1-e5e3e90d0e40"),
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "ais_mlm",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "ais_mlm"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "ais_mlm.ko",
        "userId" : UUID("bec76659-235a-44b8-8816-08a1de983c80"),
        "user" : "ko",
        "db" : "ais_mlm",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "ais_mlm"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
> use ais_mlm;        
switched to db ais_mlm
> db.createUser(
...     {
...       user: "admin",
...       pwd: "admin",
...       roles: [ "userAdmin" ]
...     }
... )
uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: User "admin@ais_mlm" already exists :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1362:11
@(shell):1:1
> show users
{
        "_id" : "ais_mlm.Admin",
        "userId" : UUID("04c87ab3-4129-4e8f-ab8a-d76c385dc5d4"),
        "user" : "Admin",
        "db" : "ais_mlm",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "ais_mlm.admin",
        "userId" : UUID("e7f7d693-151b-4db7-b3c1-e5e3e90d0e40"),
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "ais_mlm",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "ais_mlm"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "ais_mlm.ko",
        "userId" : UUID("bec76659-235a-44b8-8816-08a1de983c80"),
        "user" : "ko",
        "db" : "ais_mlm",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "ais_mlm"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

but cannot connect to mongodb
what is error
why it happen
I tried already 2 days
so frequent errors
Is this string url method deprecated or not
How can connect to mongodb by admin access
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using incorrect authentication database:

```
  authSource=admin
```

you need to change to:

```
  authSource=ais_mlm
```

Answer (score 0):

The users are created in database `ais_mlm`, thus you must use `authSource=ais_mlm` rather than `admin`.

See [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)